# $PATH error on a terminal

Tags: terminal, path

Before you raise your pitchforks, this is NOT another "How do I change my $PATH variable value?" question. I had installed [Oh my zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/) on my machine(Macbook Pro), and didn't like it. So I uninstalled it.

Ever since I installed it I get the following when I run the $PATH command:

```
Anups-xxxx-xxx% $PATH
zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
```

How do I get rid of the bit that says `zsh: no such file or directory`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: err, there is no $PATH command. If you want to see your PATH you have to run `echo $PATH`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so you've got a good understanding of $PATH and how it's used, but you're mistaken in thinking that it's a command. In Bash (and other shells), words prefaced by a dollarsign are variables. You can change the value of $PATH with the `export` command (as you probably already know).

`export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/something/you/need/bin`

So in your shell when you just type `$PATH` you're basically telling your shell to run the command `/usr/bin/:/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/etc//etc//etc/` which isn't a valid shell command.

@patrix was right, you should use `echo` to inspect your $PATH. I suspect that the "zsh: no such file or directory" is just your shell telling you that your command doesn't make sense.

Comment: Zsh expanded the variable, then tried to interpret it as a command named `bin` contained in some impossible directory specification.

Answer (score 1):

If you think there should be a `path` command, use this:

```
alias path='printf "${PATH//:/\\n}\n"'
```

This will display the contents of your `$PATH`, one element per line.

```
[665] mbp13 $ path
/opt/local/bin
/opt/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
...
[666] mbp13 $
```